# want to build automate ticket booking application for the college project

Tags: python, selenium

want to build automate ticket booking application for the college project  that can go to the website and enter all the detail by going to the travel website but I don't know which software tool and language to use please help.

Comment: Use selenium with python. If you need help I can give you my discord and I can help you out.

Comment: sure I truly appreciate please tell me how to join your discord

Comment: My name is ZEUS: https://discord.gg/rxNNHYN9EQ

Answer (score 2):

For many reasons, I think Selenium will be your best options.

1. Selenium is a set of powerful tool for testing web applications across different browsers and platforms.
2. Selenium has been around for a long time. It has big community and many tutorials. When you stuck, it easier to find solutions on the Internet than any other tool. It big point because you still a college student and you need some guidance.
3. Selenium support many language so you can choose which one you most comfortable to work with. But i still recommend using Java or Python. They already have some powerful library support testing activity and plenty of document to follow.

Java + Selenium + TestNg

Python + Selenium + Pytest

### Reference

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

Comment: THANK YOU so much for sharing the advice greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the Selenium python library. It is used for application testing.

check out the website for the docs
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: THANK YOU so much for sharing the advice greatly appreciated